# Amazon AWS S3 file naming strategy for performance

Tags: file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, naming-conventions, naming

I am currently utilizing the following naming scheme:

```
/#{bucket_name}/#{customer_name}/fi/le/na/filename.jpg
```

So an image for a file named `dsca007.jpg` for customer `bent` would be stored here:

```
/images/bent/ds/ca/00/dsca007.jpg
```

But I can understand that S3 wants a different form like this:

[image]

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXHw0Xae2ww#t=535

I understand that they want me to change my naming scheme to something like:

```
/#{bucket_name}/fi/le/na/#{customer_name})filename.jpg
```

But then he shows this slide in the youtube video:

[image]

Does that mean that my first approach was fine?

I really liked the first structure better because I was able to get a list of files owned by one customer, is there a way to list all files under a customer with the last mentioned naming scheme?

It was also quite easy to figure out how much storage each customer was using by running this command:

```
s3cmd du s3://images/#{customer_name}
```

How can I do that with the new naming scheme?

Comment: Is your workload routinely exceeding 100 requests per second against Amazon S3?

Comment: Not at the moment, I just don't want to change it if I hit the limit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you won't use some unique string when building a key, you'll reach very soon the problem of a key override.

dsca007.jpg is not very unique. there is a big chance that a file with the same name will be uploaded to your s3 bucket.
In this case you'll lost the old file or get an error, depends on your configuration.

e.g. this is what we are using:
`https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/user_media/videos/screenshots/cmXRyLRQxe9R139023426817_vid001.jpeg`

where the prefix: cmXRyLRQxe9R139023426817_ is a self generated string we build and concat to the original file name: vid001.jpg before uploading to s3.

Comment: I got in touch with Craig Carl from Amazon which told me that what you are doing is correct.

Comment: Starting all the S3 keys with the same prefix like "media/" does not meet the AWS guidelines for high volume access regularly scaling above a hundred requests per second. You need to spread the initial characters of the prefixes across different characters.

Comment: Actually, a static prefix is considered to be just fine: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

Comment: @CashIsClay yes and no: taken from here there is a trade off in both approaches:

"The intended point is that you can't have randomness on the start of a key, as well as folder-based lifecycles. You have to pick."

https://github.com/open-guides/og-aws/issues/86

Comment: @VolodymyrMetlyakov That is not entirely correct. Slowly incrementing prefixes (ie. dates) are bad because they create write-heavy "buckets" but an entirely static prefix is fine because the sharding happens further into the prefix/filename.

Comment: The link has gone invalid. Does @AmitTalmor, or anyone else, have a new URL for the image?

Comment: @Devon_C_Miller - hey, do you mean this url?  https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/user_media/videos/screenshots/cmXRyLRQxe9R139023426817_vid001.jpeg  - if yes, it is a dummy one. just showing the structure of such url.

Comment: @AmitTalmor -  Ah, it did not register that it was an example. I thought it was a link to something about structuring names. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: Are dates still considered a bad practice? Is this with respect to dates just beneath the bucket with no prefix? Eg `s3://2024-03-28` vs `s3://my_prefix/2024-03-28`?